# Saving string as text file is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to save some string to a text file, but nothing is happening and no error being thrown.

```
 Dim sb AS new StringBuilder()
   .../...
 Dim filePath = Server.MapPath("/my/path") & "mytextfile.txt" 
 Dim w As StreamWriter
 w = File.CreateText(filePath)
 w.Write(sb.ToString())
 w.Close()
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you missing a forward slash between the path and the filename?

Comment: I didn't put one. should I?

Comment: Yes, or use Path.Combine if you don't want to bother this.

Comment: Without it you create a file named 'pathmytextfile.txt' in the 'my' folder. Path.Combine as suggested is the way to go

Comment: Also use the relative ~/ at the begining when you're referencing paths.

Comment: I've used something like `Dim filePath = Path.Combine("~\\my\\path", "mytextfile.txt")`, but I got an error: Directory not found.

Comment: Adding a slash worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using a "using".  Every time you need to update the file, you can just insert these four lines.

```
Using w As StreamWriter(File.CreateText(filePath))
w.Write(sb.ToString())
w.Dispose()
End Using
```